# Validar registro de un formulario

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un formulario que me inserta unos datos que son id_tarea (el id de la tarea asignada), contenido (el contenido de esa tarea) y id_estudiante (id de estudiante que responde la tarea).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el codigo para insertar

```
<?php

include '../modelo/ConMod.php';

//$trol = $_POST["trol"];

$tusuario = $_POST["tusuario"];
$tdescripcion = $_POST["tdescripcion"];
$ttarea = $_POST["ttarea"];

 $query = "";

        $query = "INSERT INTO respuesta_tarea (contenido,id_estudiante,id_tarea)
           VALUES ('$tdescripcion','$tusuario','$ttarea')";

 

 if ($db->query($query) === TRUE) {
header("Location: materiasestudiante.php");
 }
 else {
 echo "Error al crear la materia." . $query . "<br>" . $db->error; 
   }
 
 mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

quisiera que por favor me guiaran acerca de cual es la mejor manera de validar que ese estudiante no pueda volver a responder esa tarea, la verdad no se como empezar, espero haberme hecho entender, gracias de antemano.

Comment: La solución correcta para esto es: 1º. En la tabla declarar una restricción `UNIQUE (id_tarea, id_estudiante)` la cual impedirá que una misma fila tenga el mismo `id_tare, id_estudiante`; 2º. En el código PHP, antes de insertar puedes hacer un `SELECT COUNT(*)  .... FROM  .... WHERE id_tarea=elValordeIdTarea AND id_estudiante=elValorIdEstudiante`, verificar si el resultado es igual a `0` (no existe esa combinación) y si es así insertar.

Comment: gracias, lo intente pero al poner esa restricción UNIQUE, otro estudiante diferente no puede responder la misma tarea, el navegador me arroja lo siguiente: Error al crear la materia.INSERT INTO respuesta_tarea (contenido,id_estudiante,id_tarea) VALUES ('kjlk','114 ','90 ')
Duplicate entry '90' for key 'id_tarea'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer a través de la base de datos con una Restricción ÚNICA de SQL (UNIQUE).

Esa restricción se puede indicar al momento de crear la tabla e incluso cuando la tabla ya está creada.

Caso 1: al crear la tabla

```
CREATE TABLA respuesta_tarea(
    contenido varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    id_estudiante INT NOT NULL,
    id_tarea INT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (id_estudiante, id_tarea)
)
```

Caso 2: tabla existente.

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_respuesta_tarea UNIQUE (id_estudiante, id_tarea);
```

Esto hará que cada vez que hagas un INSERT el motor de base de datos va a verificar que no se repita la tarea y ya se encuentra registrada la nueva tarea que intentas registrar, el dbms lanzará una exepción y no te dejará insertar el valor.

El manejo de la excepción lo puedes hacer con php y responderle al usuario que la tarea que intenta registrar ya se encuentra almacenada por ejemplo.

En el caso de que no quieras hacerlo a través de la base de datos podrías hacerlo con php, y para ello antes de hacer el INSERT tendrías que hacer una consulta a la base de datos para verificar si ese registro ya existe o no. Y quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

include '../modelo/ConMod.php';

//$trol = $_POST["trol"];

$tusuario = $_POST["tusuario"];
$tdescripcion = $_POST["tdescripcion"];
$ttarea = $_POST["ttarea"];

# Consulta para verificar si ya existe la tarea
$query = "SELECT id_estudiante, id_tarea FROM respuesta_tarea WHERE id_estudiante=$tusuario AND id_tarea=$ttarea LIMIT 1";

// Si ya existe
if($db->query($query)) {
    echo "Error la materia ya existe en la base de datos "; 
} else { # Si no existe entonces guardas el la nueva tarea
    $query = "";
    $query = "INSERT INTO respuesta_tarea (contenido,id_estudiante,id_tarea) VALUES('$tdescripcion','$tusuario','$ttarea')";

    if ($db->query($query) === TRUE) {
        header("Location: materiasestudiante.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error al crear la materia." . $query . "<br>" . $db->error;
    }
}

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Espero que ayude la información que te brindé.

Documentación: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Comment: Gracias, lo pude hacer perfectamente desde php.

Comment: De nada Sergio, fue un gusto poder apoyarte.

Comment: @SergiioRodriguez no te funcionó porque no pusiste las dos columnas dentro de la restricción `UNIQUE`, como expliqué en mi comentario. En este código faltaría verificar a nivel de PHP con un `COUNT()` antes de insertar. Aunque es opcional, teniendo la restricción `UNIQUE` de forma adecuada, yo lo haría, sobre todo para evitar saltos en la columna autoincremental. También, evita mostrar errores directos del manejador (podría haber información delicada que los hacker pueden aprovechar) y evita páginas como `w3schools`, plagada de malas prácticas. Es mejor aprender con la documentación oficial.